# Accessing a file held within a project folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, relative-path

Within Visual Studio I have got a file which I would like to get access to in one of my classes. This project is going onto source control so I'd like to use a relative path which points to where it is located inside the project. I've tried the following which always returns a `DirectoryNotFoundException`:

```
filePPT = new PowerPointFile("~/IO/ExportTools/Template.pptx");
```

And

```
filePPT = new PowerPointFile("~\\IO\\ExportTools\\Template.pptx");
```

The location of my file is in the following structure:

[image]

How can I access the file within Visual Studio using a relative path?

Comment: Did you set to copy the file when deployed?

Comment: For the .pptx file, change property as per given, Build Action: Content and Copy To output Directory: Copy Always. 
This will be solved your issue. 
And then use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location for getting Execution Path and concat the path of your pptx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "CopyToOutputDir" Property of the file to "Copy, if newer" so that it gets copied into the output folder and than create the path relative to the Startup Path of the Application aka

```
filePPT = new PowerPointFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "IO/ExportTools/Template.pptx"));
```

Comment: Probably missing something super simple here but I'm getting an error message at Application, it says "The name Application doesn't exist in the current content"

Comment: That's the Application class in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. If you have a different project type then take the appropriate class of that technique. System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, as DynamicVariable suggests, should work in almost any desktop project type.